# Spark performance issue on lots of window function and very large dataset

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am generating around 30 window functions and run it against a pretty large dataset (1.5bil records) which is 14 days worth of data. If I run it against 1 day so roughly 100mio records it takes 27 hours to compute.. Which makes me thing there must be something wrong. As a comparison the join I do on the same dataset takes 2 minutes.

```
# Window Time = 30min
window_time = 1800

# TCP ports
ports = ['22', '25', '53', '80', '88', '123', '514', '443', '8080', '8443']

# Stats fields for window
stat_fields = ['source_bytes', 'destination_bytes', 'source_packets', 'destination_packets']

def add_port_column(r_df, port, window):
    '''
    Input:
        r_df: dataframe
        port: port
        window: pyspark window to be used

    Output: pyspark dataframe
    '''

    return r_df.withColumn('pkts_src_port_{}_30m'.format(port), F.when(F.col('source_port') == port, F.sum('source_packets').over(window)).otherwise(0))\
        .withColumn('pkts_dst_port_{}_30m'.format(port), F.when(F.col('destination_port') == port, F.sum('destination_packets').over(window)).otherwise(0))

def add_stats_column(r_df, field, window):
    '''
    Input:
        r_df: dataframe
        field: field to generate stats with
        window: pyspark window to be used
    '''

    r_df = r_df \
        .withColumn('{}_sum_30m'.format(field), F.sum(field).over(window))\
        .withColumn('{}_avg_30m'.format(field), F.avg(field).over(window))\
        .withColumn('{}_std_30m'.format(field), F.stddev(field).over(window))\
        .withColumn('{}_min_30m'.format(field), F.min(field).over(window))\
        .withColumn('{}_max_30m'.format(field), F.max(field).over(window))\
        .withColumn('{}_q25_30m'.format(field), F.expr("percentile_approx('{}', 0.25)".format(field)).over(window))\
        .withColumn('{}_q75_30m'.format(field), F.expr("percentile_approx('{}', 0.75)".format(field)).over(window))

    return r_df

w_s = (Window()
     .partitionBy("ip")
     .orderBy(F.col("timestamp"))
     .rangeBetween(-window_time, 0))

flows_filtered_v3_df = (reduce(partial(add_port_column,window=w_s),
    ports,
    flows_filtered_v3_df
))
#
flows_filtered_v3_df = (reduce(partial(add_stats_column,window=w_s),
    stat_fields,
    flows_filtered_v3_df
))
```

Doing an aggregated count on ip (the partition I chose I get)

```
+------------+---------+
|          ip| count(1)|
+------------+---------+
| xxxx1      |267639084|
|xxxx2       | 82596506|
|xxxx3       | 77049896|
|xxxx4       | 73114994|
```

I wonder how I could speed up things here or what I am doing wrong that it takes such a long time to compute.

**EDIT:**

Adding a few stats

6 spark nodes - 1 TB Memory / 252 Cores in total
Spark version: 2.4.0-cdh6.3.1

Options specified

```
org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit --conf spark.executor.memory=8g --conf spark.driver.memory=8g --conf spark.local.dir=/pkgs/cdh/tmp/spark --conf spark.yarn.security.tokens.hive.enabled=false --conf spark.yarn.security.credentials.hadoopfs.enabled=false --conf spark.security.credentials.hive.enabled=false --conf spark.app.name=DSS (Py): compute_flows_window_pyspark_2020-04-14 --conf spark.io.compression.codec=snappy --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=40 --conf spark.shuffle.spill.compress=false --conf spark.shuffle.compress=false --conf spark.dku.limitedLogs={"filePartitioner.noMatch":100,"s3.ignoredPath":100,"s3.ignoredFile":100} --conf spark.security.credentials.hadoopfs.enabled=false --conf spark.jars.repositories=https://nexus.bisinfo.org:8443/repository/maven-central --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=600
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Plz go to spark UI and update dsg graph for analysis  also add spark version cluster size memory allocation etc to get proper answers

Comment: thanks for the input. I have modified my question

Comment: Did you manage to do it ?

Comment: I did yes. I introduced salting which completely fixed my issue.